# Minification: Using regex to remove linebreaks from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, regex, minify

For the pure purpose of obfuscation, the first three lines seem to clean up the script pretty nicely from unnecessary enters.

1. Can anyone tell me what the lines 1 - 4 actually do? Only thing I know from trial and error is that if I comment out the fourth line the site works, if I leave it in place the site breaks.

   ```
   <?php

   header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");   
   ob_start("compress"); 
   function compress($buffer) 
   {
       # remove extra or unneccessary new line from javascript
       $buffer = preg_replace('/([;])\s+/', '$1', $buffer);
       $buffer = preg_replace('/([}])\s+(else)/', '$1else', $buffer);
       $buffer = preg_replace('/([}])\s+(var)/', '$1;var', $buffer);
       $buffer = preg_replace('/([{};])\s+(\$)/', '$1\$', $buffer);

       return $buffer;
   }
   ```
2. Is there a better way to remove one or multiple line enters from JavaScript?

Comment: Answer to 2: Yes, use a proper JS minifier. Google's [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) was the best one last I checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dissection of all four regular expressions

Let's try and dissect each one of the regular expressions.

**First regex**

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/([;])\s+/', '$1', $buffer);
```

**Explanation**

```
(      # beginning of the first capturing group
 [;]   # match the literal character ';'
)      # ending of the first capturing group
\s+    # one or more whitespace characters (including newlines)
```

The above regular expression removes any whitespace that occurs immediately following a semicolon. `([;])` is a capturing group, meaning if a match is found, it is stored into a backreference, so we could use it later. For example, if our string was `foo; <space><space>`, then the expression would match `;` *and* the whitespace characters. The replacement pattern here is `$1`, which means the entire matched string would be replaced with just a semicolon.

---

**Second regex**

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/([}])\s+(else)/', '$1else', $buffer);
```

**Explanation**

```
(      # beginning of the first capturing group
 [}]   # match the literal character ';'
)      # ending of the first capturing group
\s+    # one or more whitespace characters
(else) # match and capture 'else'
```

The above regex removes any whitespace between a closing curly brace (`}`) and `else`. The replacement pattern here is `$1else`, which means, the string with whitespace will get replaced by what was captured by the first capturing group `([}])` (which is just the semicolon) followed by the keyword `else`. Nothing much to it.

---

**Third regex**

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/([}])\s+(var)/', '$1;var', $buffer);
```

**Explanation**

```
(      # beginning of the first capturing group
 [}]   # match the literal character ';'
)      # ending of the first capturing group
\s+    # one or more whitespace characters
(var)  # match and capture 'var'
```

This is the same as previous regex. The only difference here is the keyword - `var` instead of `else`. The semicolon character is **optional** in JavaScript. But if you want to write multiple statements in a single line, there's no way for the interpreter to know they're multiple lines, so a `;` will need to be used to terminate each statement.

---

**Fourth regex**

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/([{};])\s+(\$)/', '$1\$', $buffer);
```

**Explanation**

```
(      # beginning of the first capturing group
 [{};] # match the literal character '{' or '}' or ';'
)      # ending of the first capturing group
\s+    # one or more whitespace characters
(      # beginning of the second capturing group
 \$    # match the literal character '$'
)      # ending of the second capturing group
```

The replacement pattern here is `$1\$`, which means the entire matched string would be replaced with what was matched by the first capturing group `([{};])` followed by a literal `$` character.

### Sidenote

This answer was only meant to explain the four regexes and what it does. The expressions could be improved a lot, but I'm not going into that as it's not the correct approach. As Qtax points out in the comments, **you really should use a proper JS minifier** to achieve this task. You might want to check out [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) - it looks pretty neat.

If you're still confused how it works, don't worry. Learning regexes can be difficult in the beginning. I suggest you use this website - http://regularexpressions.info. It is a pretty decent resource for learning regular expressions. If you're looking for a book, you might want to check out [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://www.amazon.in/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) By Jeffrey Friedl.